# Plotting a graph in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph

I'm new to python and want to plot a point on graph in python..

```
X_cord=int(raw_input("Enter the x-coordinate"))
Y_cord=int(raw_input("Enter the y-coordinate"))
```

I could just figure out this much.

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org), a 2D plotting library for Python. 
For your code, this could work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # I include a module which contains the plotting functionality I need: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html
plt.plot(X_cord,   # here go the X coordinates
         Y_cord,   # here go the Y coordinates
         marker='x', # as I'm plotting only one point here, I'd like to make it extra visible
         markersize=10 # by choosing a nice marker shape ('x') and large size
         )
plt.show() # this shows the current plot in a pop-up window
```

If you would like to immediately save the figure as an image, you can also choose to replace the last line by

```
plt.savefig("my_first_plot.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
plt.close()
```

*Edit:* I spelled it out a bit more, but the main suggestion is to get to know Python better (ample tutorials on the web, this is not the place for it) and to read the matplotlib documentation if you want to know more about plotting. Hope this helps, or feel free to post specific problems you are having.

Comment: mm..could u plz elaborate it..m new to it so much of it is going over my head

Comment: @UddeshyaSingh Elaborated the code a bit, I hope it's clear. I'm pretty sure this answers your question exactly. I'd suggest going through the matplotlib documentation if you need to do more plotting, and/or post more specific problems you encounter or things you don't understand.

Answer (score 3):

python has different libraries for plotting such as matplotlib, seaborn and so on.
But the most widely used is matplotlib.

It is better to check and read their documentation.

Matplotlib:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [x_coordination]
y = [y_coordination]
plt.plot(x, y)
```

Seaborn:

```
import seaborn as sb

x = [x_coordination]
y = [y_coordination]
sb.pointplot(x, y)
```

these codes make your simple graph but, for showing your graph you should write this line below your codes.

```
plt.show()
```

This was the simplest way to plot a point on a graph.

For more details it is recommended to read the documentation.

For example:

```
plt.plot(x, y, marker="*", markersize=2, color="green")
```

or

```
sb.pointplot(x, y, markers="*", color="r")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something simpler, you can try https://quickchart.io/ which works quite nicely.  It generates a URL or you can save an image.

You can see a full example here on weather data: https://pythonhowtoprogram.com/get-weather-forecasts-and-show-it-on-a-chart-using-python-3/

(full disclosure, this is my post!)[image: Chart example]

Answer (score 0):

In your case, add the following import:

`from matplotlib import pyplot as plt`

and add this at the end after reading in X and Y coordinates from the user:

```
X_cord = float( X_cord )
Y_cord = float( Y_cord )
plt.scatter( X_cord, Y_cord )
plt.show()
```

This hopefully gives you what you want, a simple point plotted.

If you want something more, look into plt.plot for line plots.

If you want more advanced plotting, I suggest making a list of values instead of asking of unit values from user.

Comment: Yeah..this was helpful